# Different Date Format in BETWEEN condition

Tags: mysql, where-clause, between

Im newbie for sql. My code:

```
$start_date='2017-01-01';
$end_date='2016-01-31';
$this->db->where('date_note BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)). '" and "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date)).'"');
```

But in my database is like `2016-03-11 14:21:36`

How I can get this record from database with different format date? Thanks

Comment: You have an event that starts after it ends? What is it? The Big Bang?

Comment: `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date))` is a [`no-op`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) for the value you use for `$start_date`. [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) uses the passed string (`2017-01-01`) to compute its timestamp then [`date('Y-m-d')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) converts the timestamp back to a string. Guess what? It produces exactly the value of `$start_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL function [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) resolves fully your problem as it allows you to get the time you saved within your database in the format of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your SQL. It is okay to compare DATE with DATATIME(as in your database).

Here is a demo:

```
mysql> SELECT '2016-03-11 14:21:36' BETWEEN '2016-03-10' AND '2016-03-12';
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| '2016-03-11 14:21:36' BETWEEN '2016-03-10' AND '2016-03-12' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                           1 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I think there something trouble with my server

Comment: what problem do you encounter?